# Div inside anothe div does not vertically align

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I am trying to center a div within a container which all have % heights and widths. I can get the div to be horizontally aligned but not vertically.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

HTML :

```
<div id='container' >
    <div id="login">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container{
    height: 99%;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto;
}

#login{
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    border: groove 1px grey;
    margin: auto;
}
```

JsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/g83RY/

Comment: you can't align the div center vertically using css, you need to assign margin or padding dynamcally using javascript.

Comment: This is what you are looking for ? : http://jsfiddle.net/g83RY/3/

Comment: Reffer this:

[How to set div exactly in the center of screen whose size is changing dynamically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052044/how-to-set-div-exactly-in-the-center-of-screen-whose-size-is-changing-dynamicall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `position:relative; top: 35%;` to `#login`.

which is half of the remaining height in the container i.e `100 - 30 = 70` => `70/2 = 35%`.

How this work is:

```
  // 35% space on top
  // 30% space occupied by login
  // 35% space on bottom (occupied automatically)

  //which is equal to 100
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/g83RY/5/)**

Comment: I removed my `margin-top` suggestion because margin-top and margin-bottom are with respect to **width** instead of height(yeah) when dealing with percentages.

Answer (score 0):

to vertically align a div, you have to treat the div as a inline element and set the line-height of the div to be the height of the container div. that way you can call

```
line-height:y px;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a fixed height, the following should do it for you :

```
#login{     
    top:49%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g83RY/3/

Comment: that is not in middle.. your calculations are wrong. the top should be `35%` check my answer :)